# Drawing rectangle with mouse on canvas is not insync with mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, sass, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw rectangle on mouse drag over the canvas. The canavs is overlayed over html5 video js player. The rectangle is getting drawn, but it does not start getting down from the right coordinates.

My canvas (overlayed over videos) is getting rendered with some margin like space (not margin I checked it) around it. I think this is the reason for rectangle not getting in synch with mouse cursor (it's a bit off). Here is my code

```
 onMouseDown = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            
        })
        let start_x = e.clientX
        let start_y = e.clientY

        this.setState({
            is_drawing: true
            draw_start_x: start_x,
            draw_start_y: start_y
        },)
    }

onMouseMove = (e) => {
        let myCanvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
        let ctx1 = myCanvas.getContext('2d')
     
        if(this.state.is_drawing){

            ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
            ctx1.beginPath()
            let width = e.clientX - this.state.draw_start_x
            let height = e.clientY - this.state.draw_start_y
           
            ctx1.fillStyle = '#000'
            ctx.fillRect(this.state.draw_start_x, this.state.draw_start_y, width, height)
            ctx1.stroke()
        }
    }

render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='video-container data-vjs-player'>
                    <canvas
                        id="myCanvas"
                        className='myCanvas'
                        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
                        onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
                        onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
                        onClick={this.onClick}
                    />
                    <video
                        ref={ node => this.videoNode = node }
                        // onContextMenu="return false;"
                        //ref={this.video_element}
                        className="video video-js video-el vjs-big-play-centered vjs-default-skin"
                        id="video-el" loop={false} controls>
                        <source
                            src="https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    </video>
                    <button className="play-btn" onClick={this.playPause}>Play</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}
```

scss file

.video-container{

```
 background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 50%;
  height: calc(100% - 250px);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;

  .myCanvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  }
  .video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .play-btn{
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Screenshot of the app[image]

If you can see, there are margin like space around the red canvas. That is the how much my mouse and rectangle are going off I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-knuth-v7fzo?file=/src/styles.scss:0-29) is this what you are trying to achieve i had to tweak the code little bit to make it work, i think the main reason was the default margin or padding of some element. by setting

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding: 0
 }
```

at the top of `scss` file it started to draw properly.